# Associate a keyboard input with a TextField in JavaFX

Tags: java, locale, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to have two JavaFX `TextField`s, one which takes input using a standard English keyboard/language, and the other using a Japanese keyboard/language.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/834758/preserving-keyboard-layout-in-a-jtextfield) addresses the problem for Swing, but the JavaFX `TextField` doesn't have the needed `getInputContext()` method.

My plan was to either catch a focus event and change the `Locale` to Japanese, or associate a specific `Locale` with the Japanese `TextField`. However, I don't know how to actually achieve either of these.

I have a suspicion the Java [Input Method Client API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/imf/api-tutorial.html) may be needed.

I am using Windows 8, but it would be nice to have a OS independent answer.

Comment: I've found this [Enhancement request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091266) but it has not been updated since 2015-06-12. As for now it seems that there is no such functionality in JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes close that i could find was:

```
textfield.getText().regionMatches();
```

however im not sure that this is the one your looking for.

Update

i also found

```
txt_message.getText().format(Locale.JAPANESE, format, args)
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, neither of those cause the user input method to change (i.e. the keyboard layout to change).