# JavaFX - How to set default keyboard language for textfield?

Tags: input, javafx, locale, default, textfield

Is there any way to set default keyboard language?
When user type a character in textfield, the default language is English.
but i want to change default language to other language.
I can't find a solution for that.

Please help me if you know that.

Comment: I've seem a similar problem in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106420/associate-a-keyboard-input-with-a-textfield-in-javafx . The answer do not suit to it's OP, but maybe you can take a try?

Comment: Thank you. I already tried. but it's not work.